# How can I make a multicolumn table in R when one variable=0?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to make a table that evaluates two variables, like the one below:

```
  Diabetes No_Diabetes
1        0          12
2        5         234
3        7         182
4        3          57
```

By using table(x), I can get these frequencies for each individual column (in this example, Diabetes or No_Diabetes):

> table(data$bmi_cat[DIABETES==0])

```
  1   2   3   4 
 12 234 182  57
```

> table(data$bmi_cat[DIABETES==1])

```
2 3 4 
5 7 3
```

but because 1 = 0 in this example, when I try to put the two tables into one data frame, I receive an error message that states they cannot be combined because they are different lengths.

I succumbed to using for loops to make the original data frame above, but there has to be an easier way than writing 8 separate loops when "table" does this so efficiently. Any suggestions on how to combine the two tables, perhaps by finding a way to display 1 = 0 in the second table? Thanks!!!

Comment: provide some data please. `with(data, table(bmi_cat, DIABETES))` would be a guess. not just one loop but EIGHT loops? really? how.. why?..

Comment: Without data it's hard to say what's going on here, please read up on how to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, you could just run the following piece to get your table:

```
table(data$bmi_cat,DIABETES)
```

Although it's difficult to solve without data, it seems the `DIABETES` is a binary vector.
So here is an attempt to reverse engineer the problem from what you shared:

```
temp <- read.table(text="Diabetes No_Diabetes
0          12
5         234
7         182
3          57",header=TRUE)

temp
```

So lets create the two variables that you are using.

```
bmi_cat <- rep(1:4,apply(temp,1,sum))

DIABETES <- rep(rep(c(0,1),4),c(t(temp)))
```

Lets regenerate the tables you had:

```
table(bmi_cat[DIABETES==0])
table(bmi_cat[DIABETES==1])
```

Seems like we have set up the `data` suitably, now lets combine it in a `data.frame`, and run `table` on that:

```
data <- data.frame(bmi_cat,DIABETES)
table(data)
```

You actually don't need a data frame here, just following will do:

```
table(bmi_cat,DIABETES)
```